# Apache NiFi Transform Epoch Unix Time in Second to Milisecond and Extract the Month and the Year?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
   ...
  "timestamp": 1613461012
   ...
}
```

The timestamp is an epoch / unix timestamp in SECOND not in milisecond.

I would like to have the result like this:

```
{
       ...
      "timestamp": 1613461012000 //timestamp in ms
      "monthyear": 2021-02 //it can be in any format as long as it can indicate the month and the year from the timestamp
       ...
}
```

I have tried to get the timestamp in ms by using Jolt Transform like this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp": "=divide(@(1,timestamp), 0.01)"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp": "=toInteger(@(1,timestamp))"
    }
  }
]
```

but it produces 2147483647 as the result not 1613461012000 (I think this can happen because jolt can only use int).
For extracting the month and year I haven't found any solution, I think I have to get the epoch in ms first before I can do this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you try this? - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Can-JOLT-be-used-to-decompose-the-value-of-the-date-time/td-p/221506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I can solve this! Here is how I achieve that.

**Full Apache Nifi Schema:**
[image: Nifi Schema Map]

**EvaluateJSONPath Configuration:**
[image: EvaluateJSONPath]

**JoltTransformJSON**
[image]

JoltSpecification:

```
{
    "month.year": "${timestamp:toNumber():multiply(1000):format('yyyy-MM')}",
    "timestamp": ${timestamp:toNumber():multiply(1000)}
}
```